# spring boot mongodb json parse string as a date error

Tags: json, mongodb, date, parsing, spring-boot

I am new to spring-boot. I am using spring-boot version 2.0.5. I am trying to create an application which uses mongodb as  it's database. I have managed to create connection from my application to mongo server. To query my document, I have a 'timestamp' field which I use with '$lt' compactor in query.

For some reason, I always get 'org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Failed to parse string as a date' error.

My Controller Function looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/get/timestamp/{timestamp}")
public List<NEWSCollection> getByTimestamp(@PathVariable("timestamp") String timestamp) throws Exception {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+0000'").parse(timestamp);
    List<NEWSCollection> NEWSList = this.newsRepository.findAllByTimestamp(timestamp);
    return NEWSList;
}
```

And my repository 'findAllByTimestamp' function look like:

```
@Query("{ 'timestamp' : { $lt: {$date:'?0'} } }")
List<NEWSCollection> findAllByTimestamp(String timestamp);
```

My Model has 'timestamp' field declared as:

```
@Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private Date timestamp;
```

The Error log:

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Failed to parse string as a date
at org.bson.json.JsonReader.visitDateTimeExtendedJson(JsonReader.java:1057) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.json.JsonReader.visitExtendedJSON(JsonReader.java:618) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:148) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:149) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readValue(DocumentCodec.java:222) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:151) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery.<init>(BasicQuery.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.findAllByTimestamp(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.findAllByTimestamp(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.hashnews.controller.NEWSController.getByTimestamp(NEWSController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Thanks For help in advance. And pardon my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository should accept date not string.

`List<NEWSCollection> findAllByTimestamp(Date timestamp);`

Comment: This Worked. Thankyou

Comment: also I figured out this there is no need to add $date inside @Query. Spring does it for you when it sees Date as datatype